# problem when using local variable (add a place holder) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new with Rails and here is my problem.

I am trying to add a place holder text using this code:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_field :image, placeholder: "Image" %> </div>
```

However, it then shows the error:

```
"ActionView::Template::Error undefined local variable or method f for #<#
<Class:0x0000000000000009e74650>0x0000000000009ac9320>)"
```

and problem at the line:

```
<%= f.text_field :image, placeholder: "Image" %> </div>
```

I am very confused because when I search on the internet, it says that I can use that model to set the default value or something like that.

Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you see this code being used anywhere, its being used within a block where `f` is defined. It is usually something like this,

```rb
<%= form_with(model: @some_model) do |f| %>
  # Other code
  <%= f.text_field :image, placeholder: "Image" %> </div>
  # Other code
<% end %>
```

In this example, the `Form` object is passed to the block as `f`, on which we then call the method `text_field`. I am guessing you either wrote this line without the block, or you named your form param as something other than `f`.